# Handling wordpress content into ajax modal popup

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I succeed to implement this jquery modal here http://wordpressthemescollection.com/ajax-wordpress-post-popup-with-simplemodal-and-jquery-488.html with Wordpress.

However, When I click on a link that is displayed within the Modal, the parent page that is changed. Is here a way to interact only inside the modal windows ?

Thank you,
Ken.

Answer (score 0):

Your limitation here is that the "modal" div is not a separate targettable browser window. So, what you would probably need to do is to intercept any click event within the containing "modal" div, and load the page content into the modal itself.

The problem becomes even more complex if you want to then be able to do things like incorporate browser back/forward button navigation within the modal, which would require you to intercept those events and reference some stored history of which pages have been loaded into the modal.